# AJAX JQuery Load KML Layer

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps, kml

I'm trying to utilize a KML layer onto Google Maps API 3.0 using a JQuery AJAX request. This is what I have so far (not working).

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
   url : 'https://blahhhhhhhhhh.com/KML_Placemarks.kml',
   dataType : 'html',
   success : function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     var Google = new google.maps.LatLng(37.42228990140251,-122.0822035425683);
     var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: Google
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
   var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
     //url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml'
     url: data
   });

   ctaLayer.setMap(map);
   console.log(data);

   }
  });                           
 });
</script>
```

The example from the Google Maps API documentation simply has that `cta.kml` file assigned to the `url` piece. What I want to do is substitute that with the result of the AJAX request.

I feel like it's possible because the result of the `console.log(data)` reads the content it eventually needs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers) works by having Google's servers read the KML and render it as tiles (so it needs to be publicly available).  If you want to load it locally, you can look at a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/)) or roll your own to render the data as native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects, but there will be a performance hit.

This should work (if "data" is valid KML and your KML is not too complex):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $.ajax({
   url : 'https://blahhhhhhhhhh.com/KML_Placemarks.kml',
   dataType : 'html',
   success : function(data) {
     console.log(data);
     var Google = new google.maps.LatLng(37.42228990140251,-122.0822035425683);
     var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: Google
   }

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
   var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
                map: map
            });

   geoXml.parseKmlString(date);

   ctaLayer.setMap(map);
   console.log(data);

   }
  });                           
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying this solution. I've added the geoxmlfull_v3.js library to my page but it says geoXML3 not defined. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't use geoxml-v3 often.  Sounds like you are not including the script correctly.